# "Want to be able to" VS "Want be able to"

Tags: grammaticality

Which form is correct?

> I want to be able to run 3 miles even when I am very old.

> I want be able to run 3 miles even when I am very old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first option, as [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=want+be+able+to%2C+want+to+be+able+to&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) would indicate.

What bothers me, though, is how many instances of "want be able to" I found in published books. I found [dozens](http://www.google.com/#q=%22want+be+able+to%22&tbm=bks&ei=bXXiUaDZB4rlrgHnhICYCA&start=30&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.aWM&fp=7ad9311cd3a8243d&biw=1315&bih=825). Some of them are obvious typos:

> If you turn this on and someone has bugged your office and starts to listen to you he will get one awful ear ache, and **he want be able to** hear a thing you say, all he will hear will be static. [should be "he ***won't*** be able"]

and some are mere coincidence:

> Know in advance what buyers **want. Be able to** deliver anything, however rushed and however special it may be, right on the day the order is received.

For some, though, it's hard to tell if the ***want*** should be ***won't***, or if the word ***to*** was inadvertantly omitted. [For example](http://books.google.com/books?id=g-8ZAGdpaZUC&pg=PA97&dq=%22want%20be%20able%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yXniUb7zNcSVrAGj7oCoAg&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBjge#v=onepage&q=%22want%20be%20able%20to%22&f=false):

> Of course, some companies **want be able to** make late changes on project work.

That could be corrected as either:

> Of course, some companies **want *to* be able to** make late changes on project work.

or:

> Of course, some companies ***won't* be able to** make late changes on project work.

Don't ask me why so many of those could be found – I want to be able to explain it, but I won't be able to explain each one.